# NZ Invalid Use of Null

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form that opens with on OnOpen event.  Part of the event contains this code:

```
nid = Val(DMax("id2", "claims", "yr =" & yr) + 1)
nid = Val(Nz([nid], 1))
```

But, I get an "Invalid Use of Null" error when it runs.
Any ideas?

***EDIT BELOW***
Here is the full code:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
Dim lngID As Long
Dim rs As Object

Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
lngID = Val(Me.OpenArgs)
rs.FindFirst "[ID] = " & lngID
If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End If
Me.LOGID.SetFocus

'Display Suggested ID Numbers
Dim yr As Long
Dim nid As Long

yr = Format(Date, "yy")
nid = Val(DMax("id2", "claims", "yr =" & yr) + 1)
nid = Val(Nz([nid], 1))
Me.SugID = yr & "-" & nid

End Sub
```

Comment: I also tried running it this way:   nid = Nz(Val(DMax("id2", "claims", "yr =" & yr) + 1), 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double-check the value returned by the `DMax` expression.  If no rows match the criteria option (`"yr =" & yr`), `DMax` will return Null.  Or if `id2` is Null in all rows which match the criteria, `DMax` will return Null.

If the `DMax` expression returns Null, the `Val()` expression is equivalent to this:

```vba
Val(Null + 1)
```

But Null + 1 yields Null, so that is the same as asking for `Val(Null)` which triggers error #94, 'Invalid use of Null'.

I'm unsure what you want instead.  If `claims.id2` is a numeric data type, maybe this will work:

```vba
nid = Nz(DMax("id2", "claims", "yr =" & yr), 0) + 1
```

Comment: You are awesome!  That is exactly what I needed!  If everything is null, I wanted it to come back with 1.  Thanks!